# programmatically setting names of lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, namespaces

I have a `lambda` function

```
myfun=lambda x:2*x
```

if I print its name

```
print(myfun)
<function <lambda> at 0x000000000E512898>
```

Which is not very informative.

If I set its name explicitly, it works better

```
myfun.__name__='myfun'
print(myfun)
<function myfun at 0x000000000E512898>
```

Given that I have a large set of lambdas, how to perform this assignment programmatically?

The motivation for doing is is the following:

I am importing another function

```
from mymodule import f_many_args
```

In `mymodule`, it is defined as

```
def f_many_args(a,b,c):
```

However, in another script, I need to call this `f_many_args` by setting b and c using some global variables. 
Later I need to print the name of `f_many_args` and I needed it to be somewhere more informative than

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? What's the logic?

Comment: A lambda function(Actually it should be lambda expression) shouldn't even have a name as it is used to create anonymous function.

Comment: use `def` maybe?

Comment: before downvoting, clarifications to the question and answer to the comments could be waited for

Comment: You are doing a partial function from `f_many_args` by setting the args `b` and `c`, is that right ?

Comment: basically yes, I could also be using the partial module. However, if possible I would stick to lambdas

Comment: May I ask why ? The syntax to write a `partial` is quite close to the one needed to write a `lambda`, maybe even simpler. And it automatically defines the name of the partial function.

Comment: ok I will look into this library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

`myfun = lambda x:2*x`

with:

```
def myfun(x):
    """doubles the input parameter"""
    return 2 * x
```

Comment: it is a clear that a normal function definition would allow to do that. Somehow I might be reinventing the wheel

Comment: maybe, it depends - you may want to have a look at `functools.partial` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html